# Dojo grid: load data from html markup

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo, jstl, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm currently using `dojox.grid.DataGrid` for displaying data, in which a second request is sent to the server for the data. I'm using spring MVC, and hence I could fill data (from markup) using the model data in the view (using JSTL, to be exact). And I'm no where getting near in achieving this, since I cant find a way to get the data inside the grid via html markup. Does dojo grid supports filling data only via script (store)?

I found `dojox.data.HtmlStore` which could be made use of. But just making sure that there's no better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dojox.data.HtmlStore` could made use of. It's not a simple solution, but it is the simplest one.

Documentation with example can be found here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/data/HtmlStore.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `dojox.grid.DataGrid` can be defined using HTML markup.

Sample code:

```
<table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th field="fieldName" >Col1</th>
      <th field="fieldName" >Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

So in your `jsp` have the logic to generate the above structure.

More info can be found [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html)

And for the data part you can do this:

```
 <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th field="fieldName" get="myData.getCol1">Col1</th>
          <th field="fieldName" get="myData.getCol2">Col2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
```

Javascript Function:

```
myData.getCol1 = function(colIndex,item){
  return "<place the actual content from your jstl variables here>";
};

While
```

the above solution works its not a smarter way, please use the store and return a constructed json object from server.

Comment: That just defines the grid. Can you fill data in the same? That's the question.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's not working for me.
Will be kind enough if u could let me know the documentation (with example). Documentation and support is the worst part of dojo framework.